# Get the correct character/string from the ones formatted in a wrong font?

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, fonts

I don't really know what kind of this task to call. For some characters/string, if you display them in a TextBox with some font (I call it Font 1), it displays them correctly. But if you change the font of TextBox to another one (I call it Font 2), the character/strings may be displayed wrong (wrong font). What I want is how to convert those characters/string (as displayed in Font 2) to some corresponding characters/string/values (as displayed in Font 1). I have to do this because in my language, there are not any character like the ones displayed in Font 2.

To make it clearer, for example:

- I've encountered a case in which the correct character was 'ă', however there was another 'expression' like '¨' which will be displayed exactly as 'ă' in Font 1, however in Font 2, it's displayed as '¨'. '¨' is not a character/letter in my language alphabet. It looks like that this is related to Font issue. This is like a problem with Input and Output:

  1. **Input**: The weird/wrong character (like as '¨') and the Font in which that weird/wrong character displays correctly (like as 'ă'). That Font is Font 1 as I called above.
  2. **Output**: The correct character (like 'ă'). I'm sure this character should be displayed correctly in almost Unicode Font. So the specified Font to display the output correctly is not necessary to mentioned here, and if it is a condition for the output (choose some specified Fonts for displaying the output correctly), I think it'll be OK because I intend to display the output characters in some fixed Font.

One of the 'converter' (calling it converter is not exact, maybe a translator) I have already is any TextBox. This should be called translator because it can help you translate the weird/wrong character to the correct one (you can see the output), however it's not a converter because you can't grasp the output, for example, select and copy it to Clipboard and paste to another textbox (such as Google search box). The TextBox operates like a translator, it receives the input (the weird/wrong character is assigned for the Text property and the Font is assigned for the Font property) and gives out the output (the correct character but as I said, you can only see it, not grasp/get it or at least get the corresponding character which is displayed correctly in another Font).

If this can't be done, I'm afraid that I have to add a column called '**FontName**' or '**FontFamily**' to my table so that every time I query the text from my table, I have also to query the corresponding Fonts to display the texts correctly on my forms/grids. This is one of the most annoying things I've ever known.

I hope you understand my problem. As I said, I even don't know what kind of task it is, but you may know. Please help me out.

Thanks!

## UPDATE

I want to give an example of the converter, see it as a function/method like this:

```
public char GetCorrectChar(char c){
   switch(c){
      case '¨': 
         return 'ă';
      case 'Ç'
         return 'ầ';
      ....
   }
}
```

This function is possible to implement, however it requires me to collect all the possible pairs (of the input chars and output chars) and I'm not sure if it's efficient. Thanks!